# How can I group my dataframe and draw a scatter plot for my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, scatter-plot

I have extracted a pandas dataframe where each row can belong to one of 24 clusters.

```
                date  cluster             tweet_id   id
0   2021-05-09 15:08:48       15  1391409828233351168    0
1   2021-05-09 07:29:08        7  1391294148200837122    1
2   2021-05-09 07:29:05        7  1391294136830005248    2
3   2021-05-09 07:28:02        7  1391293869799743489    3

4   2021-05-09 07:27:10        7  1391293650836017155    4
..                  ...      ...                  ...  ...
195 2021-05-07 04:08:05        4  1390518778191089666  195
196 2021-05-07 04:07:57        4  1390518742715600898  196
197 2021-05-07 04:07:10        4  1390518546321575936  197
198 2021-05-07 04:06:58        4  1390518497097261058  198
199 2021-05-07 04:06:16        4  1390518318617006083  199
```

How can I group the data based on the cluster it belongs to and how can I draw a scatter plot where x axis(cluster) = [1,2,3 ...24] and y-axis = id ?
I tried the following code but it's wrong:

```
y = df['id']
x = df['cluster']

df.plot.scatter(x=x, y=y)
plt.show()
```

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
date.plot.scatter(x='cluster', y='id')
plt.show()
```

The x and y args are names of the columns you wish to plot. You were passing two Pandas Series instead.